# Is this product of 8 quaternions a real value?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, clifford-algebras

I'd like to know the product of 8 quaternions $$(a+bi+cj+dk)(a-bi+cj+dk)(a+bi-cj+dk)(a+bi+cj-dk)(a+bi-cj-dk)(a-bi-cj+dk)(a-bi+cj-dk)(a-bi-cj-dk)$$

I'd like to know if it is real?

PS : $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Why don't you just put it into a computer algebra system, expand it and then look at the coefficients of $i,j,k$?

Comment: @Bemte I don't have access to one

Comment: There are free ones  around, e.g. gap. If you are more into magma, you can use a light version for free here: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

You could also write a short program in any language you want or just do it by hand, I don't see where there is a problem here.

Comment: I tried wolfram but its not accepting 8 term products.

Comment: @Bemte : Can you give me the code for this?

Comment: I guess it is $a^8+b^8+c^8+d^8$. Intuitive reason : due to symmetry!

Comment: I guess you could just sit down for about half an hour and compute it on a sheet of paper. Might be easier than guessing things here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Let $a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4$, then your equation evaluates to $$550800+331200i+57600j-489600k$$

Also, notice that your equation has a slight asymmetry. You can see it in the signs:
$$+++, -++, +-+, ++-$$
$$+--, --+, -+-, ---$$
notice how the 6th and 7th sign pattern seems to be swapped.

If you use this sign pattern, which is more symmetric:
$$+++, -++, +-+, ++-$$
$$+--, -+-, --+, ---$$
then you'll get
$195600+ 550400i -396800j+ 396800k$

In any case, the result is not real.

If you use this sign pattern:
$$+++, -++, +-+, ++-$$
$$--+, -+-, +--, ---$$
then the quaternions do pair up into conjugates, without ever needing to swap places (swapping places is not usually allowed, since quaternions are not generally commutative), like this:
$$q_{+++}q_{-++}q_{+-+}(q_{++-}q_{--+})q_{-+-}q_{+--}q_{---}$$
$$=q_{+++}q_{-++}q_{+-+}(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)q_{-+-}q_{+--}q_{---}$$
(since real numbers commutes with quaternions,)
$$=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)q_{+++}q_{-++}(q_{+-+}q_{-+-})q_{+--}q_{---}$$
$$=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2q_{+++}(q_{-++}q_{+--})q_{---}$$
$$=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^3q_{+++}q_{---}$$
$$=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^4$$
which is real.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks

Comment: oops? No it isn't

Comment: I guess it is $a^8+b^8+c^8+d^8$. Intuitive reason : due to symmetry!

Comment: looks like you are right, but if you can explain the non commutativity doesnt show up here due to symmetry!

Comment: "It's just the product of 4 pairs of quaternion conjugates" isn't just enough due to non commutativity. You need a better argument.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju I'm sorry about the bad mistake. Now It's fixed.

Comment: $a=b=c=d=1$ gives just $-256j $.

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate : If you have time, can you verify this Q&A : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2304984/2987